# How to release Singleton object in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, automatic-ref-counting

I have created singleton object, at one point of time have to release the singleton object. How to release the singleton object in non-ARC and ARC?

Comment: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Comment: look under non arc code in the link i provided

Comment: - (oneway void)release {
  // never release
}

how we can use this method ?

Comment: If you want to release it, 99.99% of the time that means you *shouldn't make it a singleton*. Can you explain your use case?

Comment: for eg: i created one label instance and after some time have to release the object.

Comment: You don't release a singleton object. Ever. If you want to release it, it isn't a singleton.

Comment: Having one Label instance, isn't a reason to have a singleton. Singleton you make to assure there will never be any other instance of that class. Just one. In your case, just don't make it a singleton. However, the answers here are valid, provided you never want to have another label object again, once you disposed of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the single instance as a global variable of the class, for example:

```
static MyClass *_instance = nil;
```

instead of being `static` local within the `sharedInstance` class method, then you can create a destroy method like this:

```
+ (void)destroyInstance
{
    _instance = nil;
}
```

However one issue I can see is the use of the `dispatch_once_t` that is commonly used to ensure atomic initialization; I think you would need to avoid using it in this case as it's not possible to reset it.  This might not be an issue if you never intend to call `sharedInstance` again, once it's been destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface MySingleton : NSObject
static dispatch_once_t predicate;
static MySingleton *sharedSingletonInstance = nil;

@implementation MySingleton

+ (MySingleton *)ShareInstance {
    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
        sharedSingletonInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedSingletonInstance;
}

+ (void)destroyMySingletonInstance {
    sharedSingletonInstance = nil;
    predicate = 0;
}
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"------");
}

// TODO
...
@end
```